# como faz pra mostrar só as lojas do bairro selecionado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quando clicasse no bairro 1, todas as div(class loja) que nao pertencesse a esse bairro passaria a ficar em display:none. 
pode ter varios bairros entao queria um jeito que nao precisasse atualizar toda vez que tivesse um bairro novo

```
<div>
   <p>Bairro 1</p>
   <p>Bairro 2</p>
   <p>Bairro 3</p>
   <p>Bairro 4</p>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 1</P>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 2</P>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 3</P>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 4</P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ney, você fazer simplesmente assim:

```js
$('.selectBairro p').click(function(){
  var bairro = $(this).text();
  $('.loja').hide();
  $('.loja p:contains(' + bairro + ')').parent().show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectBairro">
   <p>Bairro 1</p>
   <p>Bairro 2</p>
   <p>Bairro 3</p>
   <p>Bairro 4</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 1</p>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 2</p>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 3</p>
</div>

<div class="loja">
   <p>Bairro 4</p>
</div>
```

Uso o seletor [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Mas esse método funciona apenas caso na sua loja tenha um parágrafo com o nome do bairro. Não é algo muito manipulável devido o seu método de escolhe. Mas para o que tem, esse serve.

Para ser algo mais seletivo, adicione uma `class="name"` a cada parágrafo com o nome do bairro, assim, pode fazer ao invés disso:

```
  $('.loja p:contains(' + bairro + ')').parent().show();
```

Isso:

```
  $('.loja .name:contains(' + bairro + ')').parent().show();
```

Comment: Obrigado de novo samir :) vou fazer esse metodo que vc falou sim

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer isso com JavaScript nativo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/o9jbcq7x/

```
function getElements(sel) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    return [].slice.call(els);
}

function procurar(e) {
    var procurado = e.target.innerHTML;
    bairros.forEach(function(el) {
        el.parentNode.style.display = el.innerHTML == procurado ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
}

var escolhas = getElements('div:first-of-type > p');
var bairros = getElements('.loja > p');

escolhas.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', procurar);
});
```

O teu HTML pode dar azo a problemas, tens de ter a certeza que tens exatamente o mesmo HTML. O melhor seria usares classes ou atributos `data-` para saberes melhor quais os elementos a selecionar...